# Laravel 4 route NOT passing in a username

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-4, controller, routes, url-routing

**Hi, I have been trying to solve this issue for hours how, researched Stack Overflow and many other websites, but no luck.**

```
//-------Route
Route::get('/profile/{firstName}', array(
    'as' => 'userProfile',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
));

//--------Controller 

class ProfileController extends BaseController {

    public function user($firstName) {

        $user = User::where('firstName', '=', $firstName);

        if($user->count()) {
            //First record return from the query
            $user = $user->first();

            return View::make('profile.user')
                ->with('user', $user);
        }

        return "sorry, 404";
        //return App::abort(404);
    } 
}
```

**Finally link:**

```
 <li><a href="{{URL::route('userProfile') }}"> My Profile </a></li>
```

**------------------------------**

*If I put the username into the URL manually, it works, however when I clicked on the link I get **localhost:8000/profile/{firstName} with "sorry, 404"**

Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route `userProfile` requires the parameter `firstName` so you have to pass that in when generating the url:

```
{{ URL::route('userProfile', Auth::user()->firstName) }}
```

(How you get the `firstName` in the view doesn't matter I just used `Auth::user` since I thought this might be your use case)